# Root user not having permissions

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, su

My root user is not working how he should.
`sudo` works perfectly but if I login with root, autocomplete does not work for all commands which need root permission and I couldn't execute a file owned by one of my users. All things work if I enter root by `sudo -i` but not with `su root` or in textmode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

`sudo su -`

command .

Running `su root`  does not execute your profile , and any path variables set explicitly will not be available , might be the reason if missing auto complete.

from error in comments ,right solution would be to change permission of your script,

```
chmod u+x /home/marten/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run
./home/marten/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run
```

OR if you can't do that

```
bash  ./home/marten/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run
```

and it should run.

Comment: I have the same problem with `sudo su`

Comment: And the main problem was that my root user hasn't got the permission to execute ap file owned ba a normal user.

Comment: with the dash at end , or 

sudo su - root

could you also paste what error you are getting.

Comment: `root@marten-desktop:~# /home/marten/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run
-bash: /home/marten/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run: No permission` There is no execute permission set but as root I should be able to run everythin right? (Or am I incredibly stupid)

Comment: could you try 

"bash /home/marten/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run"

Comment: Tank you very much, it worked fine but why did it work?

Comment: if you don't have execute permission even root cant help you , so by providing script as argument to bash command , you don't need execute permission anymore ?

Comment: Use `sudo -s` to get a root shell rather than `sudo su`, which ends up needlessly executing two processes: `sudo` to become root, then `su` to execute a shell.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `sudo su`. This elevates privileges to Super User. Remember to type in `exit` after you're finished though. Constantly running as SU is dangerous. If you forget to exit, you're exposing your system.

Comment: Thanks for answering but it didn't work. I should add that this error came up when I updated to 14.10

Comment: @Marten Can you clarify the problem that you're having then? Your question makes it hard to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English. I'll try to explain my Problem better. I wantet to install Nvidia Drivers and perssed Ctrl+Alt+F4 logged in to root (I set the password before) and typed  `/home/marten/Downloads/N` and then I pressed tab for autocomplete but it didn't. Then I typed it in manualy and it gave me `bash: Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run: No permission`

Comment: @Marten Well, that's normal. Bash can't autocomplete file names or directories. Here's how to do what you're asking: type in `cd Downloads`. You need to make the file executable as well. To do that, type in `chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run`. Then you simply run the file by typing `./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.47.run`.

Comment: But I had no permission to execute as root user. And it also doesn't autocomplete to `apt-get install` anymore but when I enter `sudo apt-get in` as my normal user it autocompletes.

Comment: I see what you mean now. This doesn't work on my computer either. I'm not sure why, but autocompletion is disabled running as root.

Comment: Thanks that worked but why doesn't autocomplete work when I login to root by `su root` or `sudo su`but with `sudo -i` it works.

Comment: @Marten That one's a mystery to me.

Comment: Hahah well thats fine. So thank you too for helping and also teaching me that it's normal.

Comment: Use `sudo -s` to get a root shell rather than `sudo su`, which ends up needlessly executing two processes: `sudo` to become root, then `su` to execute a shell.